# Why does Moment.JS not parse 24 hour dates correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

Whenever I parse dates using moment.js & node, it is exactly 12 hours out from what it should be. Consider the following test:

```
var moment = require('moment');

var dt1 = moment('14:00, 10 Jun 2014', 'HH:mm, DD MMM YYYY').toDate();
console.log('dt1:' + JSON.stringify(dt1, null, 4));

var dt2 = moment('02:00, 10 Jun 2014', 'HH:mm, DD MMM YYYY').toDate();
console.log('dt2:' + JSON.stringify(dt2, null, 4));
```

It gives the output:

```
dt1:"2014-06-10T02:00:00.000Z"
dt2:"2014-06-09T14:00:00.000Z"
```

Its almost like its parsing it using some crazy timezone and not just parsing the date in my local timezone as I want, which I would have thought would be be the default behaviour.

How can I make it work properly?

Comment: The `Z` in the output represents [Zulu or UTC time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones) and is included because `Date`s are [stringified with `toISOString()`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.44).

Comment: All I want to do is parse the rather strange textual date above, then get it into MongoDB as a DateTime field. If you can explain how to get the local date out of a moment I'll accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment.js is working correctly. Source of your problem is JSON.stringify that converts date to UTC. So you need to add your timezone to timestamp to fix that. And simplest way to do that is to warp your first moment object to second one for changing of format and set default format using format call without parameters (look for Default format here).

```
moment(moment('02:00, 10 Jun 2014', 'HH:mm, DD MMM YYYY').toDate()).format();
```

**Update:**

It's more simple as @MattJohnson figure out. Not sure why it's not worked before for me, but it's just need to be:

```
moment('02:00, 10 Jun 2014', 'HH:mm, DD MMM YYYY').format()
```

Comment: The `format` function is the key here.  Wrapping the moment in another moment is not required.

Comment: I just check this before answer and found out that moment.format() not working with dates that not follow ISO-8601 formats. So it's needed.

Comment: Strange. I'll check what I get last time.

Answer (score 2):

Try like the following

```
var dt1 = moment('14:00, 10 Jun 2014', 'HH:mm, DD MMM YYYY').format('HH:mm, DD MMM YYYY');
```